# error: spawn /Applications/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/git/bin/git ENOENT

Tags: reactjs, github, github-desktop

I'm running GitHub desktop on a Mac, have never seen the below error until recently (near that time I started running React apps). I hit CLOSE on the error and it just reopens again. I have to restart. At a stand still....

spawn /Applications/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/git/bin/git ENOENT

any ideas?